# In XDB Migration Tenant which connection string of MongoDB to be shared

Tags: xdb, migration

In `xDB` Migration from 8.2 to 9.1, 8.2 `Mongo DB` have connection string for `analytics db`, `tracking live`, `history` and `contact` db.

Which connection string needs to be given in `mongo db` provide under `xDB` tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're asking about `Mongo Database Endpoint` item used in `xDB Data Migration`.

It should use `analytics` connection string:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right connection string for the mongodb endpoint is the **analytics** database.

First off all you  need to add a new connection string to the ConnectionString.config that points to the 8.x MongoDB

```
<add name="82_analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/82_analytics" />
```

You will use 82_analytics like an endpoint. 
Here you find more details: https://neilkillen.com/2017/11/29/how-to-migrate-your-sitecore-8-x-mongodb-contacts-to-xconnect/